# How to get a value of function corresponding to certain coordinates without actually replacing the values in code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, numpy

I have an array of values x and y and have a function f(x,y). I want to get the value of f(x1,y1) corresponding to (x1,y1). How can we get it?

```
khmax = np.arange(0,0.5,0.001)
Ncmax = np.arange(0,0.5,0.001)
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(Ncmax,khmax)

sum_real = 0
sum_imag = 0
for l in range (0,N):                                                # C_jl * P_lj
    sum_imag = sum_imag + (matrix_C[j_node-1][l])*(np.sin(Y*(x_j(l+1)-x_j(j_node)) / hmax))
    sum_real = sum_real + (matrix_C[j_node-1][l])*(np.cos(Y*(x_j(l+1)-x_j(j_node)) / hmax))
Aj_real = (X * sum_real)
Aj_imag = (X * sum_imag)
G_imag = -Aj_imag + (2 * (Aj_real) * (Aj_imag)) / 2 - ((3 * ((Aj_real)**2) * (Aj_imag)) -((Aj_imag)**3)) + ((4*(Aj_real)*(Aj_imag))*((Aj_real)**2 - (Aj_imag)**2))/24
G_real = 1 - (Aj_real) + (((Aj_real)**2 - (Aj_imag)**2)/2) - ((((Aj_real)**3 - 3*(Aj_real)*((Aj_imag)**2)))/6) + ((((((Aj_real)**2 - (Aj_imag)**2 )**2- 4*((Aj_real)**2)*((Aj_imag)**2))))/ 24)

mod_G = (((G_real)**2) + ((G_imag)**2))**(0.5)
```

In this code mod_G is a function of (khmax, Ncmax). I want to get the value of mod_G corresponding to (khmax,Ncmax) suppose(0.1,0.1). I don't want to put the value of (khmax, Ncmax) into the function directly(i.e not replacing khmax with 0.1 and Ncmax with 0.1). How can I get mod_G without doing this?

Comment: You need to search on how to create a function in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try defining it as an actual python function, i.e. using the `def` keyword and then calling it with the two parameters? This way you could just easily call it as `mod_G(0.1,0.1)` without changing anything else.